# why does user process need to have kernel space in its virtual memory address space.

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I can understand the rationale to divide memory into kernel space and user space when dealing with physical addresses, so user process won't be able to contaminate kernel space.

With virtual address and page table, isolation between process is guaranteed by page table mapping(multiple process won't be able to corrupt each other's memory, and they have the view of owning the whole memory), but why do we still need to reserve kernel space in user process's virtual memory address space, as far as I know, user process can't read or write into kernel space, so what is the point? is it for backward compatibility?

Comment: In short, this is for **fast switching** from user space to kernel space and back (e.g. on system call, or timer interrupt). Because kernel's mapping is already exist in user'space mapping, there is no needs to update mapping on such switch.

Comment: So, kernel space's mapping is also loaded in user process's page table, in the event of a system call, same page table can be used. That makes a lot of sense, thanks!